# XCode IB: How to hide a button and make the next one in the grid take its space in (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit

I have a screen with 4 buttons and I need to hide some of them, for example, if I decide to hide button 3, then button 4 will occupy that blank space that button 3 left.

What I have:

1 2

3 4

What I want

1 3

4

Comment: Maybe UICollectionView would be a good fit? 1 button per cell and use an array of buttons as the data source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better adding them on collection view , and hide and show item in list as you want